# Rmpi.dll "could not be found" with DeinoMPI and Rmpi

Tags: r, mpi

I'm trying to set up MPI with DeinoMPI on Windows. I've installed DeinoMPI and have my cluster set up there, but when I run `library(Rmpi)` after starting Rgui.exe through the cluster I get the following error:

```
> library(Rmpi)
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Rmpi', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'D:/Programs/R-3.1.0/library/Rmpi/libs/x64/Rmpi.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

In addition: Warning message:
package ‘Rmpi’ was built under R version 3.1.1 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rmpi’
```

Looking at that directory, `Rmpi.dll` is present in the directory and has read/write access. Anyone have any ideas why it says 'the specified module could not be found'? Or is there some additional config necessary perhaps?

Additionally, if I run Rgui.exe outside of the DeinoMPI cluster and run `library(Rmpi)`, I receive the following pop-up:

[image: error message]